# How does $60,000 salary in Sweden translates to salary in Seattle (US)?

Tags: usa, sweden, salary

I'm an Asian working in IT field in Sweden. I earn around $60,000 (before taxes). If I have salary of around $80,000 (before taxes) in Seattle, would it give same living quality or is it a bad salary for that city?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

[Comparison of living costs Stockholm vs Seattle](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/comparison/stockholm/seattle?)

I can't comment on taxes etc (I believe they are likely to be higher in Stockholm), but for pure costs it appears Seattle is about 14% more expensive.