# Swedish salary concern

Tags: working-visas, sweden, salary

I have received an offer of 35000 SEK/month from a Swedish company. My location would be Ludvika, Sweden. I am married, no children.

Would this be sufficient to have a good living and save a little?

Comment: Practically a duplicate: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14894/how-does-60-000-salary-in-sweden-translates-to-salary-in-seattle-us Note that there are many more of [these types of questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+salary) on the site, where the answers will contain links to salary calculators.

Comment: @JanDoggen I didn’t find any question specific to sweden salary expectations. I agree there are many general questions on salary and calculators. But one has to agree that this is a very critical part of moving to another country and explanatory & specific answers like @Rsf’s could help making the appropriate decisions. No offence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardly but still doable, but don't think about saving

35,000 will get you 26,000 in your bank [(calculate here)](https://www.ekonomifakta.se/Fakta/Skatter/Rakna-pa-dina-skatter/Rakna-ut-din-skatt/#&&/wEXAQUEY2FsYwUBMYDp9Tkj4OGAN4R9N1IUN54CiLz9yKMG5G2iLHW2Pox3)

An apartment could cost [around 5000](https://mobil.blocket.se/annonser/dalarna/bostad?cg=3000&m=61&r=6&st=u)

Two public transportation tickets would be around 1800, electricity 500 (heating is usually included afaik), mobile phone 200 (2 simple pre paids at 95) and you still need food, hot clothing and the occasional something for you apartment